# Regex - Capturing a group based on a pattern

Tags: regex, regex-group, recurring

I'm trying to extract match patterns like:

AA/**8G+8G+8G+8G**/WITHOUT *

AA/**8*G+8*G+8*G+8*G**/WITH *

AA/**8G+8*G+8*G+8*G**/MIXED, THIS IS NOT SUPPORTED YET

using the following regular expression:

https://regex101.com/r/zemJ8H/1

but it matches only 8G+8G+8G+

because the pattern is identified as 8G**+**

Is there any way to include the last 8G (without +) in the group?

Comment: I'm trying to extract the content between couples of / if a valid pattern is found. With "valid pattern" I mean combination of numbers (1 or 2 digits), followed by a letter (either M or G) and a + symbol or nothing (if it's the latest item of the sequence). So I'm expecting to obtain 8*G+8*G+8*G+8*G or 8G+8G+8G+8G in the list of matches. I tried with (?<=/)([0-9]{1,2}[\*]*[GM][\+]{0,1}?)\1+ but the last item of the sequence is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression takes care of all three cases, including the mixed one:

```
(?<=/)([0-9]{1,2})[*]*([GM])[+]?(\1[*]*\2[+]?)+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jPJzQY/2)

The idea is to separate out the capturing of digits (new `\1`) from letters (the `\2`) and use both captures in the repeating group `(\1[\*]*\2[\+]?)+` at the end of the expression.

[image: Regex groups]

Comment: Are there regex dialects that require backslash escapes of meta characters in square brackets?  I would have thought `[*]`, not `[\*]`

Comment: This is the expected solution! Thanks! How can I mark it as the solution?

Comment: @DanFarrell You are right, I copy-pasted parts of OP's regex into my version. Backslashes are not required. I edited the answer, and updated the demo. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
AA/(8\*?G\+?)+/
```

https://regex101.com/r/zemJ8H/2

What about something like this?  AA followed by a plan followed by any number of sequences containing an 8, optionally a *, a G , and optionally a following +, finally followed by a +.

Comment: To didn't have any examples in the regex 101 if any other strings to match, but if desired it would be an easy matter to change the 8 and G to character classes

Comment: Thanks, but this is matching "too much" :) The solution I was looking for is the one provided by dasblinkenlight